# how to find objects with autorelease message?

Tags: objective-c, autorelease

My application crashes when the autorelease pool is released. The reason seems to be that the object with autorelease message is sent a release message sometime before the pool is released, hence the application crashes for object which is already released.

Hence I want to find which objects have a pending autorelease message, so that I can balance the retain .. release/autorelease messages to that object

Answer (score 1):

if you dont know about 'NSZombieEnabled' you definitely need to check it out - Instructions are [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled)

It won't tell you which objects are in the autoreleasepool but it will tell you which objects are being over-released.

In brief:

1)Double-click an executable in the Executables group of your Xcode project.

2)Click the Arguments tab.

3)In the "Variables to be set in the environment:" section, make a variable called "NSZombieEnabled" and set its value to "YES".

Comment: thanks ,I used your method and came to know about class of the object. This helped me to narrow down the list of possible objects.